How Upstream and sync fork differs
Is there any difference between sync fork button (and then git pull origin) on Github and upsteam  (git remote add -f upstream <repourl>)?
What does connecting your fork with the upstream repository really mean?
Because upstream is the original repository from which your fork was created, which is similar to a fork and then syncing it.
